# Tooltip overlap issue in highchart, can not select plotpoint on same datetime?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am facing a strange issue that is related to highchart js.I am developing a mood graph means user post his mood status using php and then after user can see his all post mood status in graph.
I am taking data object from mysql as json format with datetime and mood status value.
In this data some post id that may has same datetime so the overlap issue is occured.
So now every thing goes perfect but on same datetime the middle point can not select on hover or click.
I have created a fiddle. so please check this fiddle  the link is [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/wdpjaipur/85qk4p43/1/) or 
http://jsfiddle.net/wdpjaipur/85qk4p43/1/

```
 var categories = ['Terrible', 'Bad', 'Ok', 'Good', 'Great']
    $(function () {
        $('#containerss').highcharts({
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'x'
            },
            credits: {
                text: 'Demo',
                href: ''
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            subtitle: {},
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                    console.log(this);
                        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%a %d %b', this.value);
                    },
                    overflow: 'justify',
                    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    millisecond: '%H:%M:%S.%L',
                        minute: '%H:%M',
                        hour: '%H:%M',
                        day: '%e. %b',
                        week: '%e. %b',
                        month: '%b \'%y',
                        year: '%Y'
                    }
                },


            },
            yAxis: {
                categories: categories
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                  pointStart      : this.value,
            pointInterval   : 3600 * 1000,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    point: {

                    },
                    marker: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                },
                area: {
                    fillColor: {
                        linearGradient: {
                            x1: 0,
                            y1: 0,
                            x2: 0,
                            y2: 1
                        },
                        stops: [
                            [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                            [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                        ]
                    },
                    marker: {
                        radius: 4, enabled: true
                    },
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 1
                        }
                    },
                    threshold: null
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {

                    return 'On: ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%a %d %b %H:%M %p', this.key) + Highcharts.dateFormat('%H %M', this.point.myData) + '<br> Mood ' + categories[this.y];
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'area', marker: {
                    symbol: 'diamond'
                },
                name: 'Mood',
                data: [[Date.UTC(2016,0,10,10,38,19),1,1],[Date.UTC(2016,0,11,10,38,33),1,2],[Date.UTC(2016,0,12,10,40,03),2,6],[Date.UTC(2016,0,12,10,40,36),2,3],[Date.UTC(2016,0,13,09,41,30),4,7],[Date.UTC(2016,0,13,09,43,45),2,8],[Date.UTC(2016,0,13,09,45,00),0,9]],
            }]
        });

    });
```

Kindly help me to find the solution of overlapping issue.
Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have almost similar the same x, so tracker cannot find a point. The solution is using extra series (scatter) with points.

```
series: [{
       linkedTo: 0,
       type: 'scatter',
       lineWidth: 1,
       marker: {
         symbol: 'diamond'
       },
       data: [
         [Date.UTC(2016, 0, 10, 10, 38, 19), 1, 1],
         [Date.UTC(2016, 0, 11, 10, 38, 33), 1, 2],
         [Date.UTC(2016, 0, 12, 10, 40, 03), 2, 6],
         [Date.UTC(2016, 0, 12, 10, 40, 36), 2, 3],
         [Date.UTC(2016, 0, 13, 09, 41, 30), 4, 7],
         [Date.UTC(2016, 0, 13, 09, 43, 45), 2, 8],
         [Date.UTC(2016, 0, 13, 09, 45, 00), 0, 9]
       ]
     },{
        linkedTo:':previous',
       type: 'area',
       marker: {
         enabled: false
       },
       lineWidth: 0,
       name: 'Mood',
       data: [
         [Date.UTC(2016, 0, 10, 10, 38, 19), 1, 1],
         [Date.UTC(2016, 0, 11, 10, 38, 33), 1, 2],
         [Date.UTC(2016, 0, 12, 10, 40, 03), 2, 6],
         [Date.UTC(2016, 0, 12, 10, 40, 36), 2, 3],
         [Date.UTC(2016, 0, 13, 09, 41, 30), 4, 7],
         [Date.UTC(2016, 0, 13, 09, 43, 45), 2, 8],
         [Date.UTC(2016, 0, 13, 09, 45, 00), 0, 9]
       ],
     }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ar3zckq3/

Comment: Thank you so much for this good solution.But last middle point does not tooltip event. that was my question.

Comment: Well in my example I see tooltip per each point, also middle. Which browser do you use?

Comment: But i see two line on graph